# What kind of connector is this (something to USB 2.0)?

Tags: cable, connector

What kind of connector is this?  On the other side of this cable is a male USB 2.0 connector.
[image]

Comment: Is there any symbol on this connector or a manufacturer name?

Comment: Looks like firewire, apple cable. That or esata.

Comment: @Bodo Unfortunately there is no symbol!  On the USB side there's a standard USB symbol, but none on the connector pictured.

Comment: @Moab - I looked up pictures of both but doesn't seem to match.  Our only Apple devices are iPhones and apple firewire looks symmetric.  Esata is a flatter/wider head.

Comment: This is not a standard USB connector of any kind. It's proprietary.

Answer (score 4):

Mini USB SYNC&CHARGER Cable for htc Touch 3G Pro & similar devices.

[image]

[Source page on aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32846074801.html)

How did I find out ? [Google lens](https://lens.google/)

**Edit**:
Here's a *htc Touch 3G* for reference:

[image: htc Touch 3G]

[image]

[image source](https://www.windowscentral.com/htc-makes-touch-viva-and-touch-3g-official)